# I have an arraylist populated with information from a text file and I want to remove a specifc element

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code.  I created a method which searches through the arraylist and looks to see if there is a name match. In the "remove button" section, I call this method.  If there is a name match, then I remove that name and the birthday of that person.  My problem is that the program will only remove the first element in the arraylist.  If I try to remove any other elements, my array does not change, the element is not removed.

```
    private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //cear array
        players.clear();
        //add user input to array
        String name,birthDay;
        name = nameInput.getText();
        birthDay = birthInput.getText();
        playerInfo player;
        player = new playerInfo(name,birthDay);
        players.add(player);
        //add array to next available line in file
        arrayToFile();
    }                                         

    private void exitButonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //exits program
        System.exit(0);
    }                                         

    private void listButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        outputField.setText("");
        //clear array
        players.clear();

        //add file elements to array
        fileToArray();

        //print array
        outputField.setText(printArray(players));
    }                                          

    private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        //clear array
        players.clear();
        //add file elements to array
        fileToArray();
        System.out.println(printArray(players));
        //search array and delete player
        String name = nameInput.getText();
        String outputMessage;
        int nameFound = -1;
        nameFound = searchArray(players,name);


        if (nameFound == -1)    {
            outputMessage = "Sorry that name is not in the records.";
        } else {
            players.remove(nameFound);
            outputMessage = name + " has been removed from the records";
        }
        outputField.setText(outputMessage);

        //add updated array to file
        overwriteFile();
    }                                            


    class playerInfo    {
        String name,birthDay;

        playerInfo(String _name,String _birthDay)   {
            name = _name;
            birthDay = _birthDay;
        }
    }

    public void fileToArray() {
        //tempLine will be equal to the information on each line in the file
        String tempLine,name,birthDay;

        //makes sure you don't read past the end of the file
        try {
            //locates the file and opens it to read
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("players.txt"));

            //reads info from file, line-by-line until it sees "null" or "end of file"
            while ((tempLine = br.readLine()) !=null)   {
                //finds the reference numbers of each book
                name = tempLine;
                //finds title name
                tempLine = br.readLine();
                birthDay = tempLine;
                //adds reference number and title of each book into the array
                playerInfo playersAdded;
                playersAdded = new playerInfo(name,birthDay);
                players.add(playersAdded);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {  
        }
    }

    public void arrayToFile()    {
        Writer output;
        try {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("players.txt",true));
            output.append(printArray(players));
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(projectAgainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void overwriteFile()    {
        Writer output;
        try {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("players.txt"));
            output.write(printArray(players));
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(projectAgainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static String printArray(ArrayList <playerInfo> players) {
        String outputMessage = "";
        for (int i=0;i<players.size();i++)  {
            outputMessage += players.get(i).name + "\n" + players.get(i).birthDay + "\n";
        }
        return outputMessage;
    }

    public static int searchArray(ArrayList <playerInfo> players,String nameSearch)  {
        int nameFound = -1;
        String name;
        for (int i=0;i<players.size();i++)  {
            name = players.get(i).name;
            if (nameSearch.equals(name))    {
                nameFound = i;
                return nameFound;
            } else {
                nameFound = -1;
                return nameFound;
            }

        }
        return nameFound;
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel ageLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField birthInput;
    private javax.swing.JButton exitButon;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JButton listButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField nameInput;
    private javax.swing.JLabel nameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea outputField;
    private javax.swing.JButton removeButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You're asking about modifying an ArrayList, but the code which is doing that is buried in hundreds of lines of user interface code.  Please edit your question and remove all code which has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of the element you want to remove, and use that. The ArrayList.remove(int index) method takes the index to remove. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Did I not do that in my code?  In my searchArray() method I believe I found the index and then in the "remove button" section I removed the element in that specific index.

Comment: @Stephen, oops sorry. Yeah it looked like you did that. However, from looking at your code, I would fix your searchArray method. The logic won't return the correct answer. I would remove the returns inside the loop and the else statement. So just have one if statement that sets the int to the index of the element. and then have your return at the bottom.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot that, the program is working properly now.

Comment: @Stephen awesome! Glad I could help :) I hope you understand where the logic error occurred in you previous statement. For future reference, leave the return statement as the last thing in a method to prevent your method from returning answers you did not want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your **`searchArray`** method to this:

```
public static int searchArray(ArrayList <playerInfo> players,String nameSearch)  {
  int nameFound = -1;        
  for (int i=0;i<players.size();i++)  {
    String name = players.get(i).name;
    if (nameSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(name))    {
      nameFound = i;
      break;
    } 
  }
  return nameFound;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem.  However, I am just wondering why my code didn't work and yours did.  Does it have something to do with "break"?

Comment: You had written both if and else conditions and returning from both of it. If name doesn't match then else statement will execute and it will return from there - loop wasn't executing.
What I did is, it will break from the loop whenever there is a match. Or else loop will continue.